# Sonar displaying 0% Emma coverage report

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, emma

I agree that this question is asked many a times by many people and many solutions are already been provided. However, after referring to umpteen links, not being able to display the Emma report in Sonar is driving me crazy. Below is a description of what I am trying to do.

My java project is a multi module maven project. We are using EMMA as the code coverage tool and Jenkins to build the project, Sonar to analyze the code and configured Sonar for our build job using the Jenkins sonar plugin. Up to this point, the story is great. The problem comes when I try to reuse the reports generated by Emma during Sonar analysis. There is no apparent error in the Sonar analysis logs during the build, however, in Sonar project dashboard the coverage report is 0%. Below is configuration data that I provide in the Sonar configuration section of my Jenkins build job.

```
-Dsonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=emma
-Dsonar.emma.reportPath=/target
-Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
-Dsonar.surefire.reportsPath=/target/surefire-reports
```

Sonar Version : 3.0

Emma plugin versions:

```
emma-maven-plugin : 1.0-alpha-2 
Sonar Emma Plugin :1.0.1 
emma : 2.0.5312
```

The Maven build generates the coverage.em files in the individual modules' target folder. No coverage.ec file is generated. Is it mandatory to have both coverage.ec and coverage.em files for Sonar?

The coverage.es,html,txt,xml files are generated in the project build directory/emma folder

The Sonar analysis logs for a module looks like below.

```
[INFO] [15:06:02.829] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.emma.EmmaSensor@bfc33...
[WARN] [15:06:02.844] Resource will be ignored in next Sonar versions, index is locked: com.mycompany.mypackage.tests.util.Activator
[INFO] [15:06:02.876] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.emma.EmmaSensor@bfc33 done: 47 ms
```

The above logs make me think that Sonar is indeed doing something with the generated Emma reports, but not displaying anything on the Sonar project dashboard.

Please let me know where I may be going wrong or what additional thing needs to be done to get this working.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160062) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer.

Comment: [from the doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Emma+Plugin) it seems that there must be an .ec and an .em file. What do you see in the generated html files?

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread might me useful. http://sonar.15.n6.nabble.com/Receiving-quot-index-is-locked-quot-warning-when-Emma-sensor-runs-td4676490.html
It describes the same problem and gives you some workarounds